# Como converter HTML em JSON?

Tags: php, javascript, json

Tenho o seguinte Script:

```js
function abreJanela(URL) {
location.href = URL; // se for popup utiliza o window.open
}
```

```html
<select name="paginas" onchange="javascript: abreJanela(this.value)">
<option value="#" selected>Selecione o Estado</option>
<option value="http://webdanfortunato.com/premiumleiloes/planilhas-3-2-7/">BA</option>
<option value="http://webdanfortunato.com/premiumleiloes/planilhas-3-2-2/">CE</option>
<option value="http://webdanfortunato.com/premiumleiloes/planilhas-3-2-3/">DF</option>
<option value="http://webdanfortunato.com/premiumleiloes/planilhas-3-2-4/">ES</option>
<option value="http://webdanfortunato.com/premiumleiloes/planilhas-3-2-5/">GO</option>
<option value="http://webdanfortunato.com/premiumleiloes/planilhas-3-2-6/">MG</option>
<option value="http://webdanfortunato.com/premiumleiloes/planilhas-3-2/">MS</option>
<option value="http://webdanfortunato.com/premiumleiloes/planilhas-3-2-8/">MT</option>
<option value="http://webdanfortunato.com/premiumleiloes/planilhas-3-2-9/">PR</option>
<option value="http://webdanfortunato.com/premiumleiloes/planilhas-3-2-10/">RS</option>
<option value="http://webdanfortunato.com/premiumleiloes/planilhas-3-2-11/">SC</option>
<option value="http://webdanfortunato.com/premiumleiloes/planilhas-3-2-12/">SP</option>
<option value="http://webdanfortunato.com/premiumleiloes/planilhas-3-2-13/">TO</option>
</select>
```

Preciso dele em JSON, achei algo semelhante e muito útil neste exemplo:  https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjson_html_select

Porém no exemplo não mostra o que têm dentro do arquivo "json_demo_db_post.php" ... Alguém pode me ajudar?? Pelo que percebi se eu conseguir o conteúdo do arquivo "json_demo_db_post.php" eu consigo cumprir meu objetivo.

Comment: Pra mim não ficou bem claro o que você quer fazer... que html você quer converter?

Comment: dentro desse arqivo php tem um jason_encode($UmaArray)

Comment: Seria bom ver a estrutura que o JSON apresenta pra poder fazer algo mais preciso, não o PHP, somente o resultado dele no formato JSON.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Crie um documento PHP (ex., `pagina_com_json.php`) dando `echo` com o conteúdo em formato JSON:

```
<?php
echo '[
   { "UF": "BA", "pasta": "planilhas-3-2-7" },
   { "UF": "CE", "pasta": "planilhas-3-2-2" },
   { "UF": "DF", "pasta": "planilhas-3-2-3" }
]';
?>
```

Em seguida você puxa o conteúdo do PHP com Ajax, converte em objeto JSON com `JSON.parse()`, monta as `options` e insere no `select`:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){

   var http = false;
   http = new XMLHttpRequest();

   var url_="pagina_com_json.php";
   http.open("GET", url_, true);
   http.onreadystatechange=function(){
      if(http.readyState==4){
         var json = JSON.parse(http.responseText),
             html = '';

         json.forEach(function(e){
            html += '<option value="http://webdanfortunato.com/premiumleiloes/'+e.pasta+'">'+e.UF+'</option>';
         });

         document.querySelector("select[name='paginas']").innerHTML += html;
      }
   }
   http.send(null);

});
```

Inicialmente, deixe o `select` apenas com o primeiro `option`, os outros serão inseridos pelo Ajax acima:

```
<select name="paginas" onchange="javascript: abreJanela(this.value)">
   <option value="#" selected>Selecione o Estado</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

Dentro desse arquivo possui um Json Encoded String

Você pode gerar pelo php
utilizando o
`json_encode();` e pode converter Arrays e Retornos do banco

```
<?php
    $arr = array("MG"=>"http://site.com","SP" => "http://outro.com");
    echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

O resultado será o seguinte

```
{"MG":"http:\/\/site.com","SP":"http:\/\/outro.com"}
```

Isso provavelmente é o que está nesse arquivo

Mas como foi  citado acima você pode criar seu Json Manualmente 
[Nesse link](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json.asp)  encontrará a documentação sobre

Um exemplo crie um arquivo MeuArquivo.json

e coloque algo parecido

```
{
"estados":[
    {"UF":"MG", "LINK":"http://site.com"}, 
    {"UF":"BA", "LINK":"http://site.com"}
]
}
```

e por ai vai

Answer (score 0):

Se eu entendi você quer transformar o JSON em HTML...

Você pode criar o seu json:

```
var json = [
    {UF: 'RS', link: 'http://google.com'},
    {UF: 'SP', link: 'http://google.com'},
    //...
]
```

Fazer um loop pra ler:

```
var op = ''
for(var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
    op += '<option value="' + json[i].link + '">' + json[i].UF + '</option>'
}
```

E usar `innerHTML` para mostrar:

```
document.getElementById('id_select').innerHTML = op
```