# Mostrar JSON no HTML

Tags: javascript, html

Queria perguntar se tem como remover alguns caracteres na hora de apresentar informações de um *script*, essas informações serão apresentadas no *Browser*.
Quero remover ( "", {}, - ).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: De uma olhada nessa [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/280734/como-converter-html-em-json)

Comment: Amigo poste o código e não a imagem! As vezes a tag `<pre>` pode te ajudar... https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre

Answer (score 0, accepted):

o ideal é você converter esse json para objeto php.

utilizando a função do [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-decode.php)
Você gera um objeto e exibe dai só os dados que quer na tela. =D

```
<?php

$json = '{"foo-bar": 12345}';

$obj = json_decode($json);
print $obj->{'foo-bar'}; // 12345

?>
```

Comment: É uma forma de se fazer, mas não consideraria a ideal, é muito mais simples e rápido fazer direto no javascript

Comment: podia ter enviado um código de exemplo como não postou nada acredito que deixou aberto.